# How to interface with web XML/JSON APIs?

Tags: php, xml, json, api

I'm learning php/xml/json and everything else on my own and I was going through API's for certain things. They have documentations but I still don't get how API's work. They give you a GET link and API key, I know that you're supposed to put the API key inside the request link

How do I call this link? And what does it mean when it gives you a sample response?

Is the response supposed to come out if you got the request correct?

I'm a bit clueluess?

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In PHP you might have something like this:

```
// EDIT: only need to use urlencode() on user supplied variables
//$url = urlencode("http://xyz.com/api?apikey=foo&v1=bar&v2=baz");
$url = "http://xyz.com/api?apikey=foo&v1=bar&v2=baz";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

The `$response` will contain a string of whatever `xyz.com` outputted when you accessed `$url` (it's what you would see if you visited `$url` directly).

Your next job would be to parse `$response` based on its data structure (e.g XML, JSON, etc) so that it's usable by the rest of your code.

There are several PHP libraries for parsing XML or JSON. Personally, I prefer to use `SimpleXMLElement` and `json_decode()` which is included with PHP 5 >= 5.2.0.

Depending on the API, it will probably send you some sort of error code/response structure if it doesn't understand the request `$url` which you could check for after you parse the response.

If `$response` returns false, then typically there was some error communicating with the `$url`.

I found that an intuitive way to think about these `XHR` requests is that you're passing arguments (`GET` parameters) to a function (API URL). And the response from the API URL is like the return statement from a function.

**UPDATE:**

API example for [Groupon](http://sites.google.com/site/grouponapiv2/api-resources/deals) as suggested by OP in comments:

```
$apikey = "client_id=abcd1234567890";
$division = "division_id=chicago";
$url = "http://api.groupon.com/v2/deals?" . implode("&", array($apikey, $division));
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$deals = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($deals['deals'] as $deal){
    $format = 'Deal: <a href="%s">%s</a><br/>';
    echo sprintf( $format, $deal['dealURL'], $deal['announcementTitle']);
}
```

The above code would print out a listing of all deal titles and urls for the Chicago area. If you look at the `Sample JSON Response` sections on the Groupon API page, it will give you the entire data structure that would be mapped to the associative array `$deals`.

If any of the `GET` parameters to the API are provided by the user (e.g. from a web form), you will want to do something like `$division = "division_id=" . urlencode($user_input);`.

Comment: And you can break up the various learnings into different steps. Instead of making the api call from php (having two sources of error) just test the api call in the browser (if you don't know, GET is when the variables are appended to the url, as in dgilland's example) so you can tinker with that until you start to get a response, and then move into the php where you do something with it

Comment: I tried doing that with an api, but the urlencode doesn't work. I took that off and now I'm getting strings and stuff, but no images or anything else. just text from the site (I'm guessing). any suggestions?

Comment: My mistake with the `urlencode()`. It changes `&` to `%26`. You'd want to apply it to all user-supplied values that are passed to `$url` though. As for your specific API requests, which one are you using? Most APIs just return text.

Comment: What does that mean when you say I have to apply it to all user-supplied values? Also, I'm using http://sites.google.com/site/grouponapiv2/api-resources/deals how do I get certain values from the response? I'm thinking just like client_id? but how do I get like certain deals I would like?

Comment: wow! you are excellent! Thank you very much! I wish i could vote up! but I don't have enough points. This is great! I've been looking for an example on APIs and stuff. Thank you very much. You clarified a lot for me.

Comment: I tried the code, and I got this error : "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array ..." What does this mean? Thank you for your help

Comment: on this line `foreach($deals['deals'] as $deal){`

Comment: I forgot the second argument to `json_decode()` which should be `json_decode($response, true);`. The second argument being `true` converts it from an object to an array.

Comment: ahhh excellent! wow I have a lot to learn. Does it usually take awhile to load? I'm guessing it takes time for the server to get the contents from `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Response time will mostly depend on the API server and the size of the results.

Comment: I have a quick question. I tried to get variables that are in an array within another array. For example: "options", thats under "deals", but within options there's more values. I thought that I would use another foreach loop within the foreach loop of the deals but that didn't work out. How would I output "soldQuantity" that is within options. Also, would it be the same if its multiple arrays?

Comment: `foreach($deals['deals'] as $deal){
    $format = 'Deal: <a href="%s">%s</a><br/>';   foreach($options['options'] as $option){
    $dealer.= "<div style='float:left;'>".$option['soldQuantity']."</div>";
   
  }
    echo sprintf( $format, $deal['dealURL'], $deal['announcementTitle']);
}` blah not sure how to format this code, to make a nicer.

Comment: Change `$options['options']` to `$deal['options']`. You'll also need to initialize `$dealer = "";` before you can append text to it.

Comment: sorry, i have another question. is there another way than using foreach? or is this the only way to grab what i needed? eventually, I'll be having a lot of foreach loops?

Comment: If you have a variable number of elements in an array, you have to use some kind of loop to access each of those elements. There's `for()` and `while()` loops, but I prefer `foreach()` whenever possible.