# Helping using JSON for an API

Tags: php, json, api

I don't really understand how this API is supposed to work, as I've never worked with JSON before.

The documentation doesn't give any examples, but it says it the end-points in this API support both POST and GET operations, returning JSON.

My question is, I'm not sure exactly how to implement this, let's say I just want to pull all the data into a simple page such as this:

**City:** *Salem*

**Zip Code:** *97302*

etc...

I'm not quite sure where to start with this:

> POST http://[your RepMan hostname]/api/v1/account/reputation/current.json
>
> GET http://[your RepMan hostname]/api/v1/account/reputation/current.json
>
> Following is a list of arguments for the POST body or GET query string. All values should be properly encoded as per a normal POST body or GET query string.

```
| Field      | Ordinality | Datatype | Description
| pid        | 1          | string   | This is your partner ID as provided by us to access the API.
| apiKey     | 1          | string   | This is your API Key as provided by use to access the API.
| srid       | ?          | string   | This is the unique RepMan ID for the account. Either this or customerId must be specified.
| customerId | ?          | string   | This is your unique customer id for the account. Either this or srid must be specified.
```

> For a 200 response, you will receive the following JSON content:

```
{
account : {
    srid        : "DW5SRB36",
    lastName    : "Morimoto",
    pid         : "SRP",
    customerId  : null,
    firstName   : "Masaharu"
},
company : {
    city        : "New York",
    postalZip   : "10011",
    provState   : "NY",
    name        : "Morimoto",
    address     : "88 10th Ave"
},
visibility : {
    found       : 18,
    missing     : 9
},
reviews : {
    1star       : 5,
    4star       : 37,
    3star       : 44,
    5star       : 66,
    2star       : 5
},
competition : {
    Restaurants in New York : {
        Megu    : 1.82,
        Morimoto: 52.95,
        Matsuri : 18.13,
        Buddakan: 0.93,
        Nobu    : 26.17
    }
},
social : {
    checkins            : 5015,
    twitter_followers   : 8154,
    facebook_likes      : 1134
},
mentions : {
    07-09-2011 : {
        positive    : 0,
        neutral     : 0,
        negative    : 0
    },
    07-07-2011: {
        positive    : 2,
        neutral     : 3,
        negative    : 0
    },
    07-05-2011: {
        positive    : 1,
        neutral     : 2,
         negative   : 0
    },
    07-11-2011: {
        positive    : 2,
        neutral     : 2,
        negative    : 0
    },
    07-06-2011: {
        positive    : 5,
        neutral     : 2,
        negative    : 0
    },
    07-10-2011: {
        positive    : 3,
        neutral     : 4,
        negative    : 0
    },
    07-08-2011: {
        positive    : 1,
        neutral     : 5,
        negative    : 0
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: what language you are using to do that request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interface with web XML/JSON APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503604/how-to-interface-with-web-xml-json-apis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to try is experiment with a few requests in your web browser.  From there, it should be pretty clear what you need to do.

Start with your base URL:

```
http://[your RepMan hostname]/api/v1/account/reputation/current.json
```

Obviously, you'll have to plug in your hostname in place of `[your RepMan hostname]`.  From there, let's add a query string.  You've seen these before... they come after the question mark `?` in the URL, and contain key/value pairs in the form of `key1=value1&key2=value2`.  You have 4 variables to plugin:  `pid`, `apiKey`, `srid`, and `customerId`.  Without knowing what this web service does, it's hard to help you know what values to plug in, but here is an example:

```
http://example.com/api/v1/account/reputation/current.json?pid=12345&apiKey=asdf&srid=34&customerid=98765
```

Manually build yourself a working URL with the parameters you want, and try it in your browser.  Once you have done that, you will see some text structure come back in [JSON format](http://json.org/example.html).  This is text that is compatible with JavaScript parsers, but is in fact separate from JavaScript.

Now, how do you get this going in PHP?  A quick way is to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$response = file_get_contents('plug your URL in here');
$responseObject = json_decode($response);
print_r($responseObject);
```

Basically, `file_get_contents()` will load the data at that URL, and `json_decode()` will take the text representation of the object and turn it into a real PHP object.  From there you could do `echo $responseObject->social->checkins` or similar.

Now, you should look into using cURL instead of `file_get_contents()`.  It will give you more control over the request, and gives you easier access to response status codes.  This will be important when you want to set a time limit on that request later on, or need to handle failures.  Also, make sure that you use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build your query string.  That way, [reserved characters](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) such as spaces will be converted to their encoded form, such as `%20`.

Comment: You are doing God's work, thanks! That's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: If you prefer to work with your data as an associative array, just change `json_decode($response);` to `json_decode($response,true);`

Answer (score 2):

The URL describes the entity:

http://[your RepMan hostname]/api/v1/account/reputation/current.json - 
*The users current reputation*.

Using HTTP **GET** you can **retrive**(get) data about an entity.

Using HTTP **POST** you can **submit**(post) data to the api about an entity (update or create a new entity).

To do this just use curl as explained in many other places like:
[php: Get url content (json) with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592802/php-get-url-content-json-with-curl)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a REST based web-service.
There are two HTTP methods the API says you can use:

- GET
- POST

GET requests are in a URL that can be for example called from a web-browser like this:

```
http://host//api/v1/account/reputation/current.json?pid={some partner ID}&nextkey={next value}...
```

The question mark (?) indicates the parameter list start. Ampersand (&) separates parameters. Parameters are key=value formatted.

POST requests use the same URL but instead of parameters you bundle up the content:

```
http://host//api/v1/account/reputation/current.json
```

Then set HTTP header "`content-type`" as "`application/json`".
Then set HTTP header "`accept`" as "`application/json`".

Then, using some software (Apache HTTP client, etc), build and POST a JSON formatted message as:

```
{
  pid: "my partner ID"
  ...
}
```

References:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

[What is the difference between a HTTP-Get and HTTP-POST and why is HTTP-POST weaker in terms of security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080863/what-is-the-difference-between-a-http-get-and-http-post-and-what-is-http-post-se)