# Using serverside to connect to an API

Tags: php

How can I use PHP to connect to this API http://eol.org/api and use a method?. I'm very confused on how to begin to use it and I just want to ask for a little direction on getting started. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16798577/362536

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or a http client library such as [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) (link contains example).

I would recommend the latter option.

Comment: wow didnt know of such resource, it makes sense. thank you kindly good sir