# Call a web service through php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I am trying to call a web service (written in Java) that is in the following format URL:

```
http://geoserver.com/track?uid='user'&sdate='sdatetime'&edate='edate' 'etime'
```

It is returning JSON data in following format:

```
[{"lat":"1","lng":"2","time":"2013-06-23 14:00:42"},
{"lat":"3","lng":"4","time":"2013-06-23 14:10:10"},
{"lat":"5","lng":"6","time":"2013-06-23 14:21:00"}]
```

How can I call this URL through PHP?

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16798577/362536

Comment: BTW you've used quote blocks instead of code blocks. Click in the `{}` instead of the quote marks next time.

Comment: try json_decode($variable);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple of ways to call this using php. one method is using `curl`, another method would be using `file_get_contents`

if using `file_get_contents`

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://geoserver.com/track?uid='user'&sdate='sdatetime'&edate='edateetime'");

$output = json_decode($json);

//you can access 

 $output[0]->lat; //your object properties this way.
```